# Interpretation of a figure: mismatching confidence intervals and percentiles

Tags: confidence-interval, data-visualization, quantiles

I found a figure as follows, showing distributions of some scores at three time points:

[image]

Considering the with of 25th-75th percentiles, how can 95% CIs be so narrow? Is this erroneous?

Answer (score 1):

Confidence intervals represent a type of confidence in knowing the *mean value* in the underlying population, based on your data sample. They are often calculated from the estimated [standard error of the mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Estimate), which decreases with the square root of the number of observations. Even though the widths of the distributions are themselves large, with enough data points (sampled from a distribution that meets certain requirement) you can still get a very precise estimate of the mean value in the population.